# How to get value of start and end in dataZoom changed event in echarts baidu?

Tags: vue.js, echarts

How to get value of `start` and `end` in dataZoom changed event in echarts baidu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen to the dataZoom event dispatched by eCharts after the dataZoom has changed.

```
myChart.on('dataZoom', function(e) {
    console.log(e);         // All params
    console.log(e.start);   // Start value
    console.log(e.end)      // End value
});
```

[Documentation on dataZoom event](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/api.html#events.datazoom)

---

**When using eCharts with vue.js library:**

Template:

```
<IECharts @dataZoom="updateZoom"></IECharts>
```

Code (wrap in `methods`):

```
methods: {
    updateZoom(e) {
        // See all available properties of the event
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

[Documentation on IEcharts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-echarts-v3)

Comment: Hi, where to put this on? Currently I try using `<IECharts @dataZoom="updateZoom"></IECharts>` and then `updateZoom : function() { ... }`

Comment: I've updated my answer. I don't work with vue myself, but maybe this works. Let me know.

Comment: Hm. Another update, can you try this? Wrap it in the `methods` property, and use `updateZoom(e) {...}`

Comment: Just back and test this, and works as charm. thank you so much :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear!

Comment: @HobasMatius Can you please put the code snippet. I  tried the above method but it doesn't  seems to work. Thank you